# Several Vital functions not working after some setup changes

Tags: wifi, touchpad, internet, hdmi

I am currently in the middle of a move and as part of that move I removed all devices from my laptop.
Previously connected devices were a monitor over HDMI, the charging cable, as well as a USB hub that was connected to a Keyboard, Mouse, External Hard drive, and a USB powered lamp.
While the device was shut down I disconnected all components and packed them away. The next time I started Elementary, several functions were not working anymore:

- The Trackpad doesn't react. The USB mouse works.
- The HDMI monitor doesn't work anymore when I connected one the next time.
- There is absolutely no internet connection. Neither WIFI nor ethernet work. The options in the connectivity part of the settings only shows VPN and Proxy.

Notably, everything works perfectly as before on the dualbooted Windows 10.

Some changes I made in the days leading up to the move:

- Installed Wireguard (might impact internet functionality, but I uninstalled it already, with no change
- Installed several versions of DisplayLink drivers (might impact HDMI, but that's weeks ago, with no problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have some uncommitted changes on the drive, so I hope we can find a solution that doesn't involve reinstalling the OS.

Thanks,

Kodos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

I found a fix. Starting with the previous kernel version fixed the problem.

Select `Advanced Options for Elementary`  from the Grub Menu, and then an older Version. That fixed it for me.

Kodos

Comment: Glad you found a fix by reverting to the prior version!

A couple of things just so you can have a better understanding:

* All of the issues you dictate given the information you gave could easily be a result of a broken kernel build on update. Both Wireguard and your DisplayLink drivers were likely dkms modules, which are additional, external modules that are built into the kernel each time it's updated (That's an oversimplified and possibly not 100% correct explanation, so bear with me :)

Please mark your answer as correct.

Comment: So as I understand it, wireguard and display link could have messed up part of the kernel update? You can only mark your own answer correct after 24hrs, so I will do that once they are over.